# Register the environment varibles for TBB

Tags: c++, ubuntu-18.04, tbb

I just start to run TBB first example but I cannot solve this syntax error.

> error: ‘tbb’ is not a namespace-name

I read this page about [Register the Environment Variables](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/505529), but since I installed tbb using "sudo apt-get install libtbb-dev" I cannot find any tbbvars.[c]sh script. Can someone explain in a simple language how to find this file and register the environment variables on ubntu 18.04 and use TBB.

This is the C++ code which I compile and face this error:

```
using namespace tbb;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

---

If I include "tbb.h" I face another error which is `undefined reference to tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_initialize()`

Comment: Did you forget to include some TBB `.h` header?

Comment: If I include "tbb.h" I face another error which is 'undefined reference to `tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_initialize()'

Comment: That's a linker error, I guess. It would be helpful if you show us the command line you use to compile the code.

Answer (score 2):

`tbb` is not defined in that source file. I guess the error message is a bit misleading, even if it is true. `tbb` is not anything, including a namespace name.

So you need to define it, add `#include <tbb.h>` or something like that to get that to *compile*.

Then according to the comment, you get linker error. You need to add the library to linking. How, depends on you build system, but you probably need to pass `-ltbb` as linker flag to *gcc* command line.

Obligatory: do not use `using namespace` like that, it is inviting hard to find bugs, and results in unnecessary confusion especially if you are just learning, as you seem to be.